# Why is this postscript calculator (type 4) shading so slow to render at high zoom?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, postscript

In an effort to produce a smooth gradient to specifications, I have tried my hand at using type 4 (postscript calculator) shading, so that I can write the function that specifies the color at each point.  Here is the function I produced, which accepts two real numbers (x and y coordinates on [0,1] x [0,1]) and returns three real numbers (the r, g, b components of the color):

```
2 copy 0.25 sub exch 0.25 sub exch dup mul exch dup mul add dup .0001 le {pop 10000.0} {1.0 exch div} ifelse 
3 1 roll 2 copy 0.75 sub exch 0.75 sub exch dup mul exch dup mul add dup .0001 le {pop 10000.0} {1.0 exch div} ifelse 
3 1 roll 2 copy 0.75 sub exch 0.25 sub exch dup mul exch dup mul add dup .0001 le {pop 10000.0} {1.0 exch div} ifelse 
3 1 roll 0.25 sub exch 0.75 sub exch dup mul exch dup mul add dup .0001 le {pop 10000.0} {1.0 exch div} ifelse 
4 copy 0.0 add add add add 1.0 exch div 
dup 3 1 roll mul 5 1 roll 
dup 3 1 roll mul 5 1 roll 
dup 3 1 roll mul 5 1 roll 
dup 3 1 roll mul 5 1 roll pop 
4 copy 0.0 exch 0 mul add exch 1 mul add exch 0 mul add exch 1 mul add 5 1 roll 
4 copy 0.0 exch 0 mul add exch 1 mul add exch 1 mul add exch 0 mul add 5 1 roll 
0.0 exch 1 mul add exch 0 mul add exch 0 mul add exch 0 mul add
```

Here is the [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) code that produced the string above as well as the actual pdf file:

```
// input: a nonnegative real number r^2 (the square of the distance)
// output: min(1/r^2, 10000.0)
string ps_weight_rsquared = ' dup .0001 le {pop 10000.0} {1.0 exch div} ifelse';

// input: x and y coordinates of a vector
// output: x^2 + y^2
string ps_distsquared = ' dup mul exch dup mul add';

//input: x and y coordinates
//output: the weight at (x,y)
string ps_weight_displacement = ps_distsquared + ps_weight_rsquared;

//input: x, y
//output: weight at the vector ((x,y) - point)
string ps_naiveWeight_pair(pair point) {
  // compute displacement:
  string toreturn = ' ' + (string)point.y + ' sub exch ' + (string)point.x + ' sub exch' ;
  // compute weight from displacement:
  return toreturn + ps_weight_displacement;
}

/* The string will be an postscript calculator formula that accepts
 * a pair and returns a list of naive weights, with the deepest weight
 * on the stack corresponding to points[0].
 */
string ps_naiveWeights_pair(pair[] points) {
  string toreturn = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    if (i < points.length - 1)
      toreturn += ' 2 copy';
    toreturn += ps_naiveWeight_pair(points[i]);
    if (i < points.length - 1)
      toreturn += ' 3 1 roll';
  }
  return toreturn;
}

// input: x,y
// output: the weights of all the displacement vectors ((x,y) - points[i]), normalized so that their sum is one
string ps_partitionWeights_pair(pair[] points) {
  string toreturn = ps_naiveWeights_pair(points);

  // compute the sum of the all the naive weights:
  toreturn += ' ' + (string)points.length + ' copy 0.0';
  for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i)
    toreturn += ' add';

  // take the reciprocal of the sum:
  toreturn += ' 1.0 exch div';

  for (int i = 1; i <= points.length; ++i) {
    // multiply a weight by the sum reciprocal and roll the new weight to the back:
    toreturn += ' dup 3 1 roll mul ' + (string)(1+points.length) + ' 1 roll'; 
  }

  //discard the sum reciprocal, which is no longer needed:
  toreturn += ' pop';

  return toreturn;
}

// Assumes the weights are already on the stack, with the deepest weight
// corresponding to summands[0].
string ps_weighted_sum(real[] summands) {
  // At each step, the top element of the stack should be the sum so far:
  string toreturn = ' 0.0';
  while(summands.length > 0) {
    toreturn += ' exch ' + (string)(summands.pop()) + ' mul add';
  }
  return toreturn;
}

// input: real numbers x, y
// output: shading function based on a weighted sum of the colors, with the weight of the color of point p equal to 1/(dist to p)^2 (and the weights normalized to have sum one)
string ps_interpolate_shade(path g, pair[] points, pen[] pointcolors) {
  pair min = min(g);
  pair max = max(g);
  real[] reds, greens, blues;
  for (pen thecolor : pointcolors) {
    real[] thecolors = colors(rgb(thecolor));
    reds.push(thecolors[0]);
    greens.push(thecolors[1]);
    blues.push(thecolors[2]);
  }
  transform t = scale(1/(max.x - min.x), 1/(max.y - min.y)) * shift(-min);
  points = t * points;
  string toreturn = ps_partitionWeights_pair(points);

  toreturn += ' ' + (string)points.length + ' copy';
  toreturn += ps_weighted_sum(reds);
  toreturn += ' ' + (string)(points.length + 1) + ' 1 roll';

  toreturn += ' ' + (string)points.length + ' copy';
  toreturn += ps_weighted_sum(greens);
  toreturn += ' ' + (string)(points.length + 1) + ' 1 roll';

  toreturn += ps_weighted_sum(blues);

  return toreturn;
}

void applyInterpolateShade(path g, pair[] points, pen[] pointcolors) {
  string shader = ps_interpolate_shade(g, points, pointcolors);
  write(shader);  //output the ps string to the terminal
  functionshade(g, fillrule=rgb(zerowinding), shader=shader);
}

/********************************************/

settings.tex = "pdflatex";
size(5cm);
applyInterpolateShade(unitcircle, new pair[] {(-.5,-.5), (.5,.5), (-.5,.5), (.5,-.5)}, new pen[] {red, green, yellow, blue});
```

And here is the output, converted to a `png` file:

[image]

It's pretty much what I had in mind.

---

**The problem:** If I open the pdf file (using either Apple Previewer or Adobe Reader) and zoom in, the rendering program slows to a crawl and (according to Activity Monitor) uses 100% of the CPU (from one core; fortunately I have other cores, so other applications keep responding).  **Am I doing something in the postscript function that is too computationally intensive?** If so, am I using bugs or bad coding practices (memory leakage, too many `roll`s,...) or is it simply an inevitable consequence of the algorithm I am using (e.g., can the renderer not handle five divisions per pixel)?

Either way, why does this only show up when I zoom in? Is the renderer trying to render the whole zoomed-in image internally in case I scroll around?

Comment: At first glance, many `0 mul` and `1 mul` may be not _"**too** computationally intensive"_, but useless. And, talking of micro-optimizations, in `exch dup mul exch dup mul add` the first `exch` is useless, too.

Comment: It's not that I understand right away what this algorithm is doing and how effective. Just what's seen, immediately.

Comment: @VadimR: Things like `0 mul` and `1 mul` are present because this postscript function was constructed automatically with color components plugged in.  In this case, these numbers were all zero or one, but the method was designed for more general situations. On the other hand, the unnecessary `exch` is entirely my fault; I was translating `x^2 + y^2` and did not realize that `y^2 + x^2` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: But ultimately, I'm not terribly interested in micro-optimizations; I want to know where the bottleneck is.

Comment: PostScript is an interpreted language, for each co-ordinate you are performing some 200 operations of varying complexity. As the resolution increases (higher zoom levels) there are more pixels to be covered unless you reduce the smoothness (which you can't, in PDF), and so the number of calculations required increases geometrically (2xzoom = 4 times the number of pixels). A smart algorithm would spot a co-ordinate outside the drawing area and elide it but its possible the code isn't that smart, or that the whole figure is being drawn, In short the bottleneck is evaluating the complex function.

Comment: Make sure the program is calling `bind` on the procedure before using it. It almost certainly is, but good to check.

Comment: Umm, its a PDF file so I don't think you can use bind.....

Comment: It would help if you show us the source of the resulting PDF file, at least the part that draws this gradient-filled circle. I suspect that the PDF file fills the circular path with a Shading Pattern (see section 8.7.4 of PDF32000:2008 specification), PatternType 1 (function-based shading) with a Function of type 4 (PostScript calculator function). But in order to get an idea of how a PDF renderer renders a PDF file, we really need to see the PDF operators.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which pdf viewer you are using, but different viewers will be optimised very differently.

Shadings are designed to be interpolated, i.e. selected coordinates within the shading should be evaluated using your PS evaluator function. The vast majority of the pixels between these should be linearly interpolated. The selection of the evaluated coordinates depends on the current smoothness. In PDF that is selected using the SM entry of an ExtGState dictionary. The shading area will be decomposed until small regions are detected as being "smooth" relative to the SM value. You could try changing SM; the default in Acrobat is 0.02, but YMMV.

If your shading is taking a long time a few things could be happening. The function could be highly non-linear; exponential functions and functions with a sharp edge can prevent the detection of linearity until the regions become very small, possibly as small as 1 pixel. Alternatively, your pdf viewer just isn't optimised for shading. Or quite possibly both of these. FWIW. I can't say if this PS calculator function is a bad fit for decomposition because I can't tell what it's doing.